# Fixed End Moment for a point load at edge span

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

[image]

Usually, i solved this kind problems by divide into 3 span, AB, BC, CD
Then, using Fixed End Moment and Cross Methode to find the Moment
But, i cant find Fixed End Moment for the point load at the edge of span. Is that 0 ? From (P*a*b²/L²)

Comment: Are your members rigid or flexible?
If they are rigid, this should be equivalent to a straight beam with a 6 m span with a 4t load at 2m.